# Delegate is nil(Swift 3)

Tags: swift3

I am facing problem with delegate.
Below is DemoTable class of type UITableViewController

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol DashboardControllerDelegate{
    func companySelected()
}


class DemoTable: UITableViewController
{
    var delegate : DashboardControllerDelegate?
    var arr_string = [String]()

    init(array: [String])
    {
        arr_string = array
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
    {
        return arr_string.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    { 
        delegate?.companySelected()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

    {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            cell?.frame(forAlignmentRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 30))
        }

        cell?.textLabel?.text = arr_string[indexPath.row]

        return cell!

    }
}
```

Here is Controller Class

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, DashboardControllerDelegate 
{          
    var dataSourceTable:DemoTable?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let fruitList = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height * 0.9))
        fruitList.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let arr_Fruits = ["Mango", "Papaya", "Graps", "Apple"]

        self.dataSourceTable = DemoTable(array: arr_Fruits)
        fruitList.dataSource = self.dataSourceTable
        fruitList.delegate = self.dataSourceTable
        view.addSubview(fruitList)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() 
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()   
    }

    func companySelected()
    {
        print("Selected")
    }
}
```

Issue is the delegate function "companySelected" not invoked in ViewController class.
Help would be appreciate :-)

Comment: The default initializer `DemoTable()` creates a new instance which is different from the instance in the storyboard. You need the actual reference.

Comment: I am not using storyboard, please explain more because I'm very new to iOS

Comment: If you are new to iOS why don't you use storyboard? Creating the UI in code is a pretty advanced topic. In this case you need to add the controller to the view hierarchy.

Comment: @vadian, may you look edited code again?

Answer (score 0):

I got answer. I have to add

```
self.dataSourceTable?.delegate = self
```

in viewDidLoad()